# How to add explanatory text to an index page?

Tags: indexing

*Note: Answers about any of the index-generating packages would be beneficial, such as [`splitidx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/splitindex) or the default [`makeidx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/makeidx).*

I've seen some books with explanatory text on their index page after the **Index** title but before the actual index list. How can this be done without manually modifying the `.idx` or `.ind` files? The command `printindex` seems woefully unable.

Here's an adequate but regrettably small example:

[image]

Here's a MWE that uses the package `makeidx`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{makeidx}\makeindex
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\index{1@One makeidx entry!With a subentry}

%How to put text on the following index page?
\printindex
%Be sure to run: makeindex <filename>


\end{document}
```

Here is a MWE that uses the package `splitidx` and creates two indices:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[split]{splitidx}\makeindex
    \newindex{firstindex}
    \newindex{secondindex}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\sindex[firstindex]{1@One splitindex entry!Using firstindex}
\sindex[secondindex]{Another splitindex entry!Using secondindex}

%How to put text on the following index pages?
\printindex[firstindex][A splitindex: firstindex]
\printindex[secondindex][A splitindex: secondindex]
%Be sure to run: makeindex <filename>-firstindex; makeindex <filename>-secondindex

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the package [`imakeidx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/imakeidx) instead of `makeidx`. This package is more robust and allows:

- Index in several columns with `\makeindex[columns=n]`
- Text before of *Index* and after of *title* with `\indexprologue{Text ...}`. This command must be put exactly before of `\printindex`.
- Run `makeindex` automatically.
- Support for `splitindex` script by Markus Kohm.
- Other options described in its [documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/imakeidx/imakeidx.pdf).

### Example MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{imakeidx}\makeindex
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\index{1@One entry!With a subentry}~\index{a@Other entry}
\indexprologue{\noindent How to put text on the following index page?}
\printindex


\end{document}
```

It is also possible generate several indexes with this package. In this case you must load the package with the `splitindex` option and run `makeindex` on `<filename>-firstindex` and `<filename>-secondindex` (if `firstindex` and `secondindex` are the names of your indexes). Or to do this automatically running `pdflatex` with `--enable-write18` or `-shell-escape` options.

**Note:** It isn't necessary to put a name to all indexes (as in `splitidx`). Simply leave the "main" index nameless and name the others. And use `\makeindex` (without arguments for the *main* index) and `\makeindex[name=...,title=...]` for the other indexes. Observe the example

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[splitindex]{imakeidx}
    \makeindex
    \makeindex[name=secondindex,title=Second Index]
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\index{1@One splitindex entry!Using firstindex}
\index[secondindex]{Another splitindex entry!Using secondindex}

\indexprologue{\noindent How to put text on the following index pages?}
\printindex

\indexprologue{\noindent How to put text on the following index pages in the second index?}
\printindex[secondindex]
%Be sure to run: makeindex <filename>-splitindex; makeindex <filename>-secondindex
%Only if you didn't run pdflatex with the `--enable-write18` option.

\end{document}
```

So is created a file `<filename>-splitindex.idx` for the *main* index and `<filename>-secondindex.idx` for the second one. The *main* index uses `\indexname` for the Index's title.

### Run

```
pdflatex --enable-write18 <filename>
```

will do this automatically by you.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[splitindex]{imakeidx}
    \makeindex[name=firstindex,title=First Index]
    \makeindex[name=secondindex,title=Second Index]
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\index[firstindex]{1@One splitindex entry!Using firstindex}
\index[secondindex]{Another splitindex entry!Using secondindex}

\indexprologue{\noindent How to put text on the following index pages?}
\printindex[firstindex]

\indexprologue{\noindent How to put text on the following index pages in the second index?}
\printindex[secondindex]
%Be sure to run: makeindex <filename>-firstindex; makeindex <filename>-secondindex

\end{document}
```

Comment: I hope that the example clarify this. View edit

Comment: Yes, thank you. And surprisingly I actually didn't have to create any blank `\makeindex` to get automatic `.idx`/`.ind` processing; I just added the `--enable-write18` option to my typesetter.

Comment: Very useful package! Allows index generation in a single run.

Comment: Thanks to @egreg, the highest reputation in this community.