# How to add explanatory text to an index page without page number troubles?

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering, indexing

I like to have an introducing text after the index starts 
(in the same way as it works for the nomenclature).

Adding the `imakeidx` package to the here used `makeidx` package and writing additionally`\indexprologue{\noindent text}` will destroy the page numbering in the TOC. (as I tried with [How to add explanatory text to an index page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/202803/how-to-add-explanatory-text-to-an-index-page))

Is this somehow possible?

```
\synctex=-1
\documentclass[a4paper,latin,fontsize=10pt,headsepline,parskip=half-,index=totoc,DIV=15]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{fancybox,calc,etoolbox,lipsum}
\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}
\renewcommand{\nomname}{Glossar}
\makenomenclature
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}% scrpage2 is obsolete
  \pagestyle{scrheadings}
  \clearpairofpagestyles% \clearscrheadings, \clearscrplain are deprecated
  \automark[chapter]{chapter}
   \renewcommand*\chaptermarkformat{}% uncomment if you don't want chapter numbers in the headers
  \ihead[]{\headmark}
  \ohead[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
\usepackage[colorlinks,pdfpagelabels,pdfstartview = FitH,bookmarksopen = true,bookmarksnumbered = true,linkcolor = black,plainpages = false,hypertexnames = false,citecolor = black] {hyperref}

\newcommand{\nobreakword}[1]{\mbox{#1}}
\usepackage{makeidx}

% I need an introducing text before the index
% ......

\makeindex
\makeatletter % needed because I need separation between different items of the same starting character
  \def\@idxitem{\par\addvspace{10\p@ \@plus 5\p@ \@minus 3\p@}\hangindent 40\p@}
  \def\subitem{\par\hangindent 40\p@ \hspace*{20\p@}}
  \def\subsubitem{\par\hangindent 40\p@ \hspace*{30\p@}}
  \def\indexspace{}
  \patchcmd\theindex{\indexname}{\indexname\vspace{12pt}}{}{}
\makeatother

% write a text before the glossar!
\renewcommand{\nompreamble}{Beachte: Es gibt verschiedene Schokoladen.}
\makenomenclature

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}% because I need a custom layout
  \centering
  \vspace*{10cm}
  titlepage
\end{titlepage}

\clearpage\pdfbookmark{\contentsname}{toc}
\tableofcontents\thispagestyle{empty}

\chapter{Einleitung}
\lipsum[1]
\newpage
\lipsum[2]
\newpage
\lipsum[3]

\chapter{Nahrung im Sommer}

\lipsum[4]

\nomenclature{Banane}{Frucht}
\nomenclature{Schokolade}{Suessigkeit \\ meistens 100 g schwer}

\index{book}
\index{summer!sun}
\index{summer!Supersonnenschirm/Supersonnenbad/ \newline Supersandstrum/Supersieg}
\index{summer!heat!sweat}
\index{sound}
\index{tower}
\count255=0
\loop\ifnum\count255<30
\advance\count255 1
\expandafter\index\expandafter{\romannumeral\count255}
\repeat

\newpage{}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\vspace*{\fill}\begin{center}  \begin{Huge} Anhang \end{Huge}   \vspace*{\fill}\end{center} 
\addtocontents{toc}{\textbf{\sffamily \textcolor{white}{empty line}}\protect\par}
\addtocontents{toc}{\textbf{\sffamily \textcolor{white}{empty line}}\protect\par}
\addtocontents{toc}{\textbf{\sffamily Anhang}\protect\par}

\printnomenclature[2.5 cm]

\renewcommand{\indexname}{Stichwortverzeichnis}
\printindex

\end{document}
```

What is important:

- The page numbering in the TOC should stay the same
- The markup in the TOC should stay the same
- The headings in the document (as you see in first chapter) should stay the same

This question is proceeding to the previous intensive code work:
[How to solve the page numbering problems (in TOC, hyperref, scrheadings, nomenclature)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/236963/how-to-solve-the-page-numbering-problems-in-toc-hyperref-scrheadings-nomencl/237210?noredirect=1#comment562812_237210)
[How to set the space between two index entries with the same character](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/236817/how-to-set-the-space-between-two-index-entries-with-the-same-character/236822?noredirect=1#comment562019_236822)
[How to add a tex specific area after the nomenclature title starts?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/236878/how-to-add-a-tex-specific-area-after-the-nomenclature-title-starts/236879?noredirect=1#comment561910_236879)

---

This is the code I tried from @egreg 's answer below with success:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,latin,fontsize=10pt,headsepline,parskip=half-,index=totoc,DIV=15]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{fancybox,calc,etoolbox,lipsum}
\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}
\renewcommand{\nomname}{Glossar}
\makenomenclature
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}% scrpage2 is obsolete
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearpairofpagestyles% \clearscrheadings, \clearscrplain are deprecated
\automark[chapter]{chapter}
\renewcommand*\chaptermarkformat{}% uncomment if you don't want chapter numbers in the headers
\ihead[]{\headmark}
\ohead[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
\renewcommand*\partpagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{imakeidx} % load always before the hyperref package, otherwise it can result in problems!
\usepackage[colorlinks,pdfpagelabels,pdfstartview = FitH,bookmarksopen = true,bookmarksnumbered = true,linkcolor = black,plainpages = false,hypertexnames = false,citecolor = black] {hyperref}

\newcommand{\nobreakword}[1]{\mbox{#1}}
\usepackage{makeidx}

\makeindex[intoc,title=Stichwortverzeichnis] % no redefining is needed with \renewcommand{\indexname}{Stichwortverzeichnis} before \printindex
\makeatletter % needed because I need separation between different items of the same starting character
  \def\@idxitem{\par\addvspace{10\p@ \@plus 5\p@ \@minus 3\p@}\hangindent 40\p@}
  \def\subitem{\par\hangindent 40\p@ \hspace*{20\p@}}
  \def\subsubitem{\par\hangindent 40\p@ \hspace*{30\p@}}
  \def\indexspace{}
  \patchcmd\theindex{\indexname}{\indexname\vspace{12pt}}{}{}
\makeatother

% write a text before the glossar!
\renewcommand{\nompreamble}{Whatever you want at the beginning of the nomenclature}
\makenomenclature

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}% because I need a custom layout
  \centering
  \vspace*{10cm}
  titlepage
\end{titlepage}

\clearpage\pdfbookmark{\contentsname}{toc}
\tableofcontents\thispagestyle{empty}

\chapter{Einleitung}
\lipsum[1]
\newpage
\lipsum[2]
\newpage
\lipsum[3]

\chapter{Nahrung im Sommer}

\lipsum[4]

\nomenclature{Banane}{Frucht}
\nomenclature{Schokolade}{Suessigkeit \\ meistens 100 g schwer}

\index{book}
\index{summer!sun}
\index{summer!Supersonnenschirm/Supersonnenbad/ \newline Supersandstrum/Supersieg}
\index{summer!heat!sweat}
\index{sound}
\index{tower}
\count255=0
\loop\ifnum\count255<30
\advance\count255 1
\expandafter\index\expandafter{\romannumeral\count255}
\repeat

\cleardoublepage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{center}
    \Huge Anhang
    \addtocontents{toc}{%
        \protect\addvspace{0.5pc}% <------------- adjust to suit
        \textbf{\sffamily Anhang}\protect\par
    }
\end{center}
\vspace*{\fill}
\clearpage

\printnomenclature[2.5 cm]

\indexprologue{Whatever you want at the beginning of the index}
\printindex

\end{document}
```

Comment: In your other comment, you said you were using `imakeidx`. Are you? Not that is a different package from `makeidx`. If you are using the latter, try using the commands KOMA provides for defining an index preamble.

Comment: I was using ``imakeidx`` in addition to the ``makeidx`` and had to do some changes which resulted in creepy toc markups and wrong pagenumbers. So now I'm only using exact the here posted MWE.

Comment: Try `\setindexpreamble{some text for the preamble of the index}`.

Comment: Also, you can just use `\part*{Anhang}` and the ToC commands rather than `\newpage\thispagestyle{empty}...`. Just set the page style for parts as shown in my answer to your other question.

Comment: Your setindexpreamble command perfectly works!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There has to be a better way of writing the ToC line, but still...

```
\documentclass[a4paper,latin,fontsize=10pt,headsepline,parskip=half-,index=totoc,DIV=15]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{fancybox,calc,etoolbox,lipsum}
\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}
\renewcommand{\nomname}{Glossar}
\makenomenclature
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}% scrpage2 is obsolete
  \pagestyle{scrheadings}
  \clearpairofpagestyles% \clearscrheadings, \clearscrplain are deprecated
  \automark[chapter]{chapter}
   \renewcommand*\chaptermarkformat{}% uncomment if you don't want chapter numbers in the headers
  \ihead[]{\headmark}
  \ohead[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
  \renewcommand*\partpagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[colorlinks,pdfpagelabels,pdfstartview = FitH,bookmarksopen = true,bookmarksnumbered = true,linkcolor = black,plainpages = false,hypertexnames = false,citecolor = black] {hyperref}

\newcommand{\nobreakword}[1]{\mbox{#1}}
\usepackage{makeidx}

% I need an introducing text before the index
\setindexpreamble{some text for the preamble of the index}

\makeindex
\makeatletter % needed because I need separation between different items of the same starting character
  \def\@idxitem{\par\addvspace{10\p@ \@plus 5\p@ \@minus 3\p@}\hangindent 40\p@}
  \def\subitem{\par\hangindent 40\p@ \hspace*{20\p@}}
  \def\subsubitem{\par\hangindent 40\p@ \hspace*{30\p@}}
  \def\indexspace{}
  \patchcmd\theindex{\indexname}{\indexname\vspace{12pt}}{}{}
\makeatother

% write a text before the glossar!
\renewcommand{\nompreamble}{Beachte: Es gibt verschiedene Schokoladen.}
\makenomenclature

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}% because I need a custom layout
  \centering
  \vspace*{10cm}
  titlepage
\end{titlepage}

\clearpage\pdfbookmark{\contentsname}{toc}
\tableofcontents\thispagestyle{empty}

\chapter{Einleitung}
\lipsum[1]
\newpage
\lipsum[2]
\newpage
\lipsum[3]

\chapter{Nahrung im Sommer}

\lipsum[4]

\nomenclature{Banane}{Frucht}
\nomenclature{Schokolade}{Suessigkeit \\ meistens 100 g schwer}

\index{book}
\index{summer!sun}
\index{summer!Supersonnenschirm/Supersonnenbad/ \newline Supersandstrum/Supersieg}
\index{summer!heat!sweat}
\index{sound}
\index{tower}
\count255=0
\loop\ifnum\count255<30
\advance\count255 1
\expandafter\index\expandafter{\romannumeral\count255}
\repeat

\part*{Anhang}
\addtocontents{toc}{\textbf{\sffamily \textcolor{white}{empty line}}\protect\par}
\addtocontents{toc}{\textbf{\sffamily \textcolor{white}{empty line}}\protect\par}
\addtocontents{toc}{\textbf{\sffamily Anhang}\protect\par}

\printnomenclature[2.5 cm]

\renewcommand{\indexname}{Stichwortverzeichnis}
\printindex

\end{document}
```

[image: index with preamble]

Answer (score 1):

The `imakeidx` package should be loaded *before* `hyperref`.

Then you just need

```
\makeindex[intoc,title=Stichwortverzeichnis]
```

and, where you want to print the index,

```
\indexprologue{Whatever you want at the beginning of the index}
\printindex
```

(no `\renewcommand{\indexname}` is needed, because of the `title=` option).

After these changes to your document, the table of contents page is

[image]

While the index page is

[image]

### Note

Instead of the horrible hack you're doing for adding “Anhang” with some space before it, use

```
\cleardoublepage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{center}
\Huge Anhang
\addtocontents{toc}{%
  \protect\addvspace{2pc}% <------------- adjust to suit
  \textbf{\sffamily Anhang}\protect\par
}
\end{center}
\vspace*{\fill}
\clearpage
```

Comment: I tried to reproduce it and put the used code in my initial question. Why is the vertical spacing between Stichwortverzeichnis-IntroducingText-FirstIndexEntry different from the vertical spacing between Glossar-IntroducingText-FirstGlossarEntry?

Comment: @laminin Because so decided (wrongly) the developers of `nomencl`. If you want no space, use `\indexprologue[\vspace{0pt}]{Text}`

Comment: By your pt command (0.5pt is not possible) I can at least adjust the introducing text distance to the first entry from index plus nomenclature. But Starting from header "Stichwortverzeichnis" and introducing text is still different from "Glossar" and introducing text

Comment: @laminin The two packages use a different model, unfortunately. Add `\vspace{-6pt}` in front of the text in `\indexprologue` (adjust to get the same distance).